# Algorithm to generate a sequence proportional to specified percentage

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sequences, random

Given a Map of objects and designated proportions (let's say they add up to 100 to make it easy):

```
val ss : Map[String,Double] = Map("A"->42, "B"->32, "C"->26)
```

How can I generate a sequence such that for a subset of size `n` there are ~42% "A"s, ~32% "B"s and ~26% "C"s? (Obviously, small `n` will have larger errors).

(Work language is Scala, but I'm just asking for the algorithm.)

**UPDATE**: I resisted a random approach since, for instance, there's ~16% chance that the sequence would start with `AA` and ~11% chance it would start with `BB` and there would be very low odds that for `n` precisely == (sum of proportions) the distribution would be perfect. So, following @MvG's answer, I implemented as follows:

```
/**
Returns the key whose achieved proportions are most below desired proportions
*/
def next[T](proportions : Map[T, Double], achievedToDate : Map[T,Double]) : T = {
    val proportionsSum = proportions.values.sum
    val desiredPercentages = proportions.mapValues(v => v / proportionsSum)
    //Initially no achieved percentages, so avoid / 0 
    val toDateTotal = if(achievedToDate.values.sum == 0.0){
        1
    }else{
        achievedToDate.values.sum
    }
    val achievedPercentages = achievedToDate.mapValues(v => v / toDateTotal)
    val gaps = achievedPercentages.map{ case (k, v) =>
        val gap = desiredPercentages(k) - v
        (k -> gap)
    }
    val maxUnder = gaps.values.toList.sortWith(_ > _).head
    //println("Max gap is " + maxUnder)
    val gapsForMaxUnder = gaps.mapValues{v => Math.abs(v - maxUnder) < Double.Epsilon }
    val keysByHasMaxUnder = gapsForMaxUnder.map(_.swap)
    keysByHasMaxUnder(true)
}

/**
Stream of most-fair next element 
*/
def proportionalStream[T](proportions : Map[T, Double], toDate : Map[T, Double]) : Stream[T] = {
    val nextS = next(proportions, toDate)
    val tailToDate = toDate + (nextS -> (toDate(nextS) + 1.0))
    Stream.cons(
        nextS,
        proportionalStream(proportions, tailToDate)
    )
}
```

That when used, e.g., :

```
val ss : Map[String,Double] = Map("A"->42, "B"->32, "C"->26)
val none : Map[String,Double] = ss.mapValues(_ => 0.0)
val mySequence = (proportionalStream(ss, none) take 100).toList
println("Desired : " + ss)
println("Achieved : " + mySequence.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size))
mySequence.map(s => print(s))
println
```

produces :

```
Desired : Map(A -> 42.0, B -> 32.0, C -> 26.0)
Achieved : Map(C -> 26, A -> 42, B -> 32)
ABCABCABACBACABACBABACABCABACBACABABCABACABCABACBA
CABABCABACBACABACBABACABCABACBACABABCABACABCABACBA
```

Comment: Search keywords: weighted random number generator.

Comment: Did you notice that your output differs from mine, the first difference being at position 11? I have 5,3,3 as a closest approximation of intended *counts*: 4.62,3.52,2.86, whereas you have 4,4,3 as a closest approximation of *proportions*, with actual proportions about 36%,36%,27%. Closeness in both cases minimizing the maximal difference (“infinity norm”). There might be many more interpretations…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a deterministic approach, the most obvious solution would probably be this:

- Keep track of the number of occurrences of each item in the sequence so far.
- For the next item, choose that item for which the difference between intended and actual count (or proportion, if you prefer that) is maximal, but only if the intended count (resp. proportion) is greater than the actual one.
- If there is a tie, break it in an arbitrary but deterministic way, e.g. choosing the alphabetically lowest item.

This approach would ensure an optimal adherence to the prescribed ratio for every prefix of the infinite sequence generated in this way.

Quick & dirty python proof of concept (don't expect any of the variable “names” to make any sense):

```
import sys

p = [0.42, 0.32, 0.26]
c = [0, 0, 0]
a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
n = 0

while n < 70*5:
    n += 1
    x = 0
    s = n*p[0] - c[0]
    for i in [1, 2]:
        si = n*p[i] - c[i]
        if si > s:
            x = i
            s = si
    sys.stdout.write(a[x])
    if n % 70 == 0:
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
    c[x] += 1
```

Generates

```
ABCABCABACABACBABCAABCABACBACABACBABCABACABACBACBAABCABCABACABACBABCAB
ACABACBACABACBABCABACABACBACBAABCABCABACABACBABCAABCABACBACABACBABCABA
CABACBACBAABCABCABACABACBABCABACABACBACBAACBABCABACABACBACBAABCABCABAC
ABACBABCABACABACBACBAACBABCABACABACBACBAABCABCABACABACBABCABACABACBACB
AACBABCABACABACBACBAABCABCABACABACBABCAABCABACBACBAACBABCABACABACBACBA
```

Comment: This seems like a lot of looping for something that could be determined just by multiplying n by the scaling factors, and ordering in a deterministic way so as to equalize as much as possible the amount lost when rounded up/down. You could do simple naive rounding, then you will either have too large a value or too little. Simply adjust the results one at a time to the proportional part that is most off, until the sum is the correct number of N.

Comment: @ErikE, your approach as I understand it relies on a fixed number *n*, and even then I believe that this “ordering” part would require some looping, too. I was aiming for a potentially infinite sequence, and only low-level primitive operations with no noops hidden inside them. I'd still be interested to see your idea in more detail as a separate answer, though.

Comment: Not correct, some looping yes but only p times not n, and I'll try to make time soon.

Comment: @ErikE, what is your *p*? If that is *p* = 100, then note that the proportions are double, not int, so even a sequence of length 100 might not match the requirement exactly. To generate a sequence of *n* elements given *m* distinct symbols with associated weights, my algo requires O(*nm*) steps. You could replace the inner loop with a heap to get this down to O(*n* log *m*). There is no way to go below O(*n*) as the time complexity cannot be smaller than the length of the generated output.

Comment: you're right, you have to loop over every element no matter what. I was simply hoping to avoid the nested loop. I am not sure that's possible.

Comment: Thank you for putting me to the test. You are right! My method, he dinna wurke so whale. First, your nested loop is the best possible: it's as you say O(*nm*) and the elements not only come in a well-distributed pattern but have the least error at each step. My method did a great job of calculating the required number of each element very fast, but then... how does one turn this into a deterministic list of them in a pseudo-random order? I have a working program, but it's nondeterministic. Thank you for schooling me and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 3):

For every item of the sequence, compute a (pseudo-)random number *r* equidistributed between 0 (inclusive) and 100 (exclusive).

- If 0 ≤ *r* < 42, take `A`
- If 42 ≤ *r* < (42+32), take `B`
- If (42+32) ≤ *r* < (42+32+26)=100, take `C`

Comment: Yeah, that' what I was thinking, but is there no deterministic algorithm?

Comment: @larsmans Well that's *exactly* what I was thinking! But I'm worried about the fairness with small `n`. Is there no simple algorithm that guarantees "as fair as reasonable" with small `n`?

Comment: @LarryOBrien I prefer this answer but if you want something deterministic you should use Colin D's answer.

Comment: This can have such variation, especially for small values! `n=3` could realistically yield `AAA` which is way far from the best `ABC`. Sorry, no.

Answer (score 1):

The number of each entry in your subset is going to be the same as in your map, but with a scaling factor applied.

The scaling factor is `n/100`.

So if n was 50, you would have `{ Ax21, Bx16, Cx13 }`.

Randomize the order to your liking.

Comment: I think this is what the OP is looking for. He needs to define clear and solid rules to round the results if he want's a not too weird result when n is small.

Comment: Yes, you've described the optimal "fairness" of the generated sequence, but I was hoping for something that would generate (one of) the "most fair" sequences.

Comment: @LarryOBrien I am not sure what you mean by 'most fair', maybe you can clarify this in your question.

Comment: @ColinD I simply mean that for most allocations and most `n` the sequence will not be perfectly proportioned to the desired allocations.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest "deterministic" [in terms of #elements of each category] solution [IMO] will be: **add elements in predefined order, and then shuffle the resulting list**.

First, add `map(x)/100 * n` elements from each element x chose how you handle integer arithmetics to avoid off by one element], and then shuffle the resulting list.

Shuffling a list is simple with [fisher-yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which is implemented in most languages: for example java has [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29), and C++ has [`random_shuffle()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/)

In java, it will be as simple as:

```
int N = 107;
List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Entry<String,Integer> e : map.entrySet()) { //map is predefined Map<String,Integer> for frequencies
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.round(e.getValue()/100.0 * N); i++) {
        res.add(e.getKey());
    }
}
Collections.shuffle(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nondeterministic, but gives a distribution of values close to MvG's. It suffers from the problem that it could give AAA right at the start. I post it here for completeness' sake given how it proves my dissent with MvG was misplaced (and I don't expect any upvotes).

Now, if someone has an idea for an `expand` function that is deterministic and won't just duplicate MvG's method (rendering the `calc` function useless), I'm all ears!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>ErikE's answer</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!Array.each) {
   Array.prototype.each = function(callback) {
      var i, l = this.length;
      for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
         callback(i, this[i]);
      }
   };
}

if (!Array.prototype.sum) {
   Array.prototype.sum = function() {
      var sum = 0;
      this.each(function(i, val) {
         sum += val;
      });
      return sum;
   };
}

function expand(counts) {
   var
      result = "",
      charlist = [],
      l,
      index;
   counts.each(function(i, val) {
      char = String.fromCharCode(i + 65);
      for ( ; val > 0; val -= 1) {
         charlist.push(char);
      }
   });
   l = charlist.length;
   for ( ; l > 0; l -= 1) {
      index = Math.floor(Math.random() * l);
      result += charlist[index];
      charlist.splice(index, 1);
   }
   return result;
}

function calc(n, proportions) {
   var percents = [],
      counts = [],
      errors = [],
      fnmap = [],
      errorSum,
      worstIndex;

   fnmap[1] = "min";
   fnmap[-1] = "max";

   proportions.each(function(i, val) {
      percents[i] = val / proportions.sum() * n;
      counts[i] = Math.round(percents[i]);
      errors[i] = counts[i] - percents[i];
   });

   errorSum = counts.sum() - n;
   while (errorSum != 0) {
      adjust = errorSum < 0 ? 1 : -1;
      worstIndex = errors.indexOf(Math[fnmap[adjust]].apply(0, errors));
      counts[worstIndex] += adjust;
      errors[worstIndex] = counts[worstIndex] - percents[worstIndex];
      errorSum += adjust;
   }
   return expand(counts);
}

document.body.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = calc(99, [25.1, 24.9, 25.9, 24.1]);
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```